# Is it possible in D&D 5E to create what is essentially a floating disk powered flying machine that is steerable via moving along a ring?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, flight, weight

Would it be possible to create a spoke like (think old cart wheels) structure with a 21 foot radius with a small chamber in the middle for a floating disk, that will hold itself together and is light enough for the disk to hold along with a passenger? Wondering because in a campaign I play a wizard and if it is possible could use my spell slots of all levels to essentially fly, or at least hover. I know that it is possible to move in this way purely on the spells rules, but am more wondering if this specific structure would work so that it is also steerable. ([Speed of a Tenser's floating discmobile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64693/speed-of-a-tensers-floating-discmobile) answers if it could move, but I am asking if this specific structure would move and be steerable)

Comment: Are you trying to get the disk to propel you, or just to support you?

Comment: @MarkWells the disk is the propulsion, which is why the specific size to allow the caster to be on the disk but far enough away that it will move.

Comment: @MivaScott it mostly does, but I am wondering of this specific situation would work to allow for steering without someone elses help via moving around the ring

Comment: I'm not sure if that needs a separate question, but if so, then you should update your question to reflect the specific only. The other option is to bounty the duplicate question asking for someone to address that issue.

Comment: Also, have you discussed this plan with your DM?

Comment: TFD cheese has a long and storied tradition ever since the spell came out. 

Comment: So after reading through the answers on the linked question, the ring would work for steering, but with the materials in the world would not be able to hold itself together while still meeting the weight requirement